# Why must I have both an access modifier and a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, string

In a simple program below, why must define it as private first and then make a constructor? I think I think I understand it's first made private because you don't want it to be changed (I think) and then you define it again in public so it can be viewed in different classes, but why must I name it differently?

I tried to ask for help elsewhere and they said "in C you need a constructor for variables of a class with default parameters to initialize it. so when you run it in your main application the compiler knows what it is." But I'm not really sure what that means. It seems quite a bit complicated.

```
class Name
{
       private String first, middle, last;
       public Name(String fname, String mname, String lname)
       {
             first = fname;
             middle = mname;
             last = lname;
        }
 }
 class Program
 {
       static void Main(String[] args)
       {
           Name myName = new Name("John", "Richard", "Smith");

        }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the first paragraph you start talking about "it", but you never say what "it" is!

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. I meant why must you define your strings as a private and then again differently as other names? In other words. Why must I define first, middle, last as private strings, and then again as public strings with different names? like fname, mname, lname, and then set them equal?

Comment: You *do not* need to define fields as private (it is usually the right thing to do); also as your learning continues you'll learn of automatic properties -- where the underlying field is compiler generated and not accessible in normal code.

Comment: You're not defining them as `public string`s there...you're simply defining a `public` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The `private` keyword means that the variable is not visible outside of the class in which it defined. If you were to write code in `Main()`, for example, that attempts to access the `first`, `middle`, or `last` variables, you would get an error. The variables are privately accessible only to the code in the `Name` class.

By contrast, the constructor is `public` so that it can be made visible outside of the class in which it was defined. This is why you don't receive an error when you access the constructor from the `Main()` method.

Comment: Why do I need the private then?

Comment: @AspiringCoder2.0 - Do you mean the private variables (`first`, `middle`, and `last`)?  Without them, where would the values be stored that you are passing into the constructor (`fname`, `mname`, and `lname`)?

Comment: Because you want to protect those variables from being changed by other classes. Typically, if their values are important to the state of your class, you don't want just any ol' piece of code modifying the values without your class' knowledge.

Comment: That's what I figured, that the main reason was so they could be seen, but not changed. But Chris, you can't store values in the constructor itself? It has to be stored somewhere else?

Comment: They have to be stored somewhere else only if your class has multiple methods, and more than one of those methods needs to access the values. In your specific example, you only have one method, so it doesn't matter much. In a real world case, your class will have several methods. More than one of those class methods may need to access the `first`, `middle`, and `last` variables. Defining them at the class level makes that visibility possible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define a private variable before a constructor, although it is nice for you to get into the habit of doing so because it can help you keep your code structured and clean.

`C` isn't `C#` so no need to worry about what someone else said,

There are some changes I would make to it though.

What you're missing in your example is called a `public` `accessibility modifier` so that people can read the names that you've set, they're currently private, so nobody other than its self, knows about them...

Imagine the real world based on that example, you would like other people to be able to read your name, know who you are, but you wouldn't like them to be able to change your name at will, it's your name. So it's the same principles that are at play here, we allow others to read the value, but not write to it.

```
public class Name
{
       private string firstName;
       private string lastName;

       public Name(String firstName, String lastName)
       {
             this.firstName = firstName;
             this.lastName  = lastName;
       }

       public string FirstName { get { return this.firstName; } }
       public string LastName  { get { return this.lastName; } }
 }

 class Program
 {
       static void Main(String[] args)
       {
           Name myName = new Name("John", "Richard");
           Console.WriteLine(myName.FirstName);
           Console.WriteLine(myName.LastName);
       }
 }
```